# How to get continous data on server from client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am learning sockets here I have created a simple server & client , here when I am sending multiple times data from client side on server side only once it is reflecting kindly assist whats missing here

**Server**

```
import socket  # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()  # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()  # Get local machine name
print(host)
port = 12345  # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind(('localhost', port))  # Bind to the port
print(s)
s.listen(5)  # Now wait for client connection.
print("socket is listening")
while True:
    connection, address = s.accept()  # Establish connection with client.
    print('Got connection from', address)
    connection.send(b'Thank you for connecting')
    buf = connection.recv(64)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print(buf)
```

**Client**

```
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 12345))

send = '1'
while True:

    if send == '1':
        forsending = input("Enter data to send to server\n")

        clientsocket.send(forsending.encode())
        send = input("Do u want 2 resend\npress 1 for yes ny other for no")
    else:
        print(send)
        break
```

Also from server side why **`connection.send(b'Thank you for connecting')`** is not showing on client end

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `clientsocket.recv` on the client side

```
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 12345))

send = '1'
while True:

    if send == '1':
        forsending = input("Enter data to send to server\n")

        clientsocket.send(forsending.encode())
        buf = clientsocket.recv(64)
        if len(buf) > 0:
            print(buf)
        send = input("Do u want 2 resend\npress 1 for yes ny other for no")
    else:
        print(send)
        break
```

This pattern is called the Client/Server pattern. I would recommend using the PyZMQ library. You can read more here:

https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html